# What does "He" refer to when Sirius says "That was a noble thing you did back there. He doesn't deserve it."?

Tags: harry-potter

They come out of Shrieking Shack, where they discover that the dog is actually Sirius. Then Sirius Black says to Harry Potter:

> Sirius Black: That was a noble thing you did back there. **He** doesn't deserve  it.
>
> Harry Potter: I didn't think my dad would have wanted his best friends... to become killers.

What does "He" refer to?

Comment: All of your questions seem to be about understanding of the English language and not about the books/movies themselves: Just go back some minutes (in movie) or some pages (in the book) to answer these questions yourself, they are not hard to answer or obscur at all... That is the reason why you get so many downvotes...

Comment: I don't think that a person should be required to read the work in order to ask a question on here. But how does one dig up this quote without having some idea of its context? Can you at least describe why you have an issue with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remus Lupin & Sirius Black wanted to kill **Peter Pettigrew** for betraying Harry's parents and framing Sirius for the murder (which resulted in his incarceration in Azkaban).

But Harry stops them, saying he should face the magical courts instead (so he would get punished by the law, and in a way would exonerate Sirius for the murder, who at the time was still a fugitive).